# VBA Creating excel files based on filter results

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing an issue while trying to make a relatively simple automation work. The idea behind is to filter a field of a table, copy all the visible results, paste them in a new worksheet, save the new worksheet with the filtered value as the file name, close the new file and repeat until my list is over. Please Help!

Also this is my code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim y As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Restructure_F")
y = 2

Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(26, y).Value)

ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=Cells(26, y).Value

ws.Range("A1:O2486").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1).Paste

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\tools\Output\" & Cells(2, 13).Value

ActiveWorkbook.Close True

y = y + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: You don't save worksheets, you save workbooks, so your question is a bit confusing. And all you did was drop code, you did not explain any problem you are having getting it to work. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

i add some lanes in your code. if i understand your description it works how you want to.

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim y As Integer
'   save variable
Dim sPath As String
Dim TempWb As Workbook
Dim TempWs As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Restructure_F")
y = 2

Do While Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(26, y).Value)
    ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=ws.Cells(26, y).Value
    ws.Range("A1:O2486").Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Selection.Copy
    sPath = "C:\tools\Output\" & ws.Cells(26, y).Text & ".xlsx"
    Set TempWb = Workbooks.Add
    Set TempWs = TempWb.Worksheets(1)
    TempWs.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    TempWb.SaveAs Filename:=sPath
    TempWb.Close True
    Set TempWb = Nothing
    ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter
    y = y + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tomasz, you are great! After some modifications it worked properly! For some reason, in my system, the cell locations are inverted, e.g. I should use ws.Cells(y, 26) to define the variable column "Z".

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. correct property is ws.cells(rowindex,columnindex)